# How does class polymorphism work with pydantic models?

Tags: python-typing, pydantic

I have two classes that inherit from the same parent:

```
class ChildOne(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        extra="allow",
    )
    ...

class ChildTwo(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        extra="forbid",
    )
    ...
```

I should be able to pass ChildOne and ChildTwo to anything that accepts BaseSettings right?

I cannot figure out how to get this to work and satisfy strict type checking.

I tried this, but the cast wipes out model_config set for the child and I'm still getting the two issues commented above the return statement

```
def my_func(model: BaseSettings) -> BaseSettings:
    # Object of type "BaseSettings" is not callable
    # Return type is unknown
    return model()

# This cast seems to completely wipe out model_config
my_func(cast(ChildOne, BaseSettings))
my_func(cast(ChildTwo, BaseSettings))
```

## Edit

After some googling this works, but I'm still not 100% why or if there is a cleaner way:

```
C = TypeVar("C", bound=BaseSettings)
def my_func(model: Type[C]) -> BaseSettings:
```

Do I have to explicitly tell the type checker that I want to accept any sub class of BaseSettings because it doesn't allow that automatically? Isn't that how basic class polymorphism is suppose to work?

This ^ also doesn't really work because when I try to access fields of `C` inside `my_func` I get:

```
Cannot access member "<Some field of ChildTwo|ChildOne>" for type "BaseSettings"
  Member "<Some field of ChildTwo|ChildOne>" is unknown
```

## Edit

I wasn't using generics correctly, I need to do:

```
C = TypeVar("C", bound=BaseSettings)
# Returns same type passed in, not BaseSettings type
def my_func(model: Type[C]) -> C:
```

I'm still confused as to why I need to use generics in the first place. Would I need to do something like this in C#/Java as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here you specify the type of `model` as 'instance object of either BaseSettings class or any class, inherited from BaseSettings':

```
def my_func(model: BaseSettings) -> BaseSettings:
```

But it seems like you want to pass class itself (not an instance object of class). So, your second attempt is the right way to specify the type of `model`:

```
C = TypeVar("C", bound=BaseSettings)
def my_func(model: Type[C]) -> BaseSettings:
```

But dont forget that in this case `model` is not an instance object of class, but class itself. And it doesn't have attributes that you defined in your `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`.
You need to create an instance object of this class to access attributes.

```
C = TypeVar("C", bound=BaseSettings)
def my_func(model: Type[C]) -> BaseSettings:
    instance = model()
    # instance.some_attribute
    return instance
```

Or, do you want something like this?

```
def my_func(model: BaseSettings) -> BaseSettings:
    # model.some_attribute = something
    return model

res = my_func(ChildOne()) # passing instance
```